# Swift - tableView not reloading after adding to array

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, uitableview

I am having an issue updating my `UITableView`. I have an app that has a basic `UIViewController` with a with a navigationItem to "Add New" items to the `UITableViewContioller`. I can add the string and then dump the array to see if it has been added. The dump function shows the added item in the array but the `UITableView` does not, even after calling `reloadData`. Here is my code.

[image]

Here is the console dump after hitting save.

[image]

So you can see something is there after I save but nothing shows up on the `UITableview`.

From the `UIViewController` class I have a `UIAlertAction` to accept text and a save button.

```
      let table = TableViewController()


        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
        alert -> Void in

        let firstTextField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
        self.table.cityArry.addObject(firstTextField.text!)
        self.table.refresh()
    })
```

And from `UITableViewController` class

```
 class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var cityArry:NSMutableArray = ["Local"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

}


func refresh(){
    dump(cityArry)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cityArry.count

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->   UITableViewCell {
    let item = cityArry[indexPath.row]
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:20, y:0, width:200, height:50))
    label.text = item as? String
    cell.addSubview(label)

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    // Nothing here yet

}
}
```

Comment: You sure the `table` displaying on your screen is the one you call `refresh` on?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you should have two separate view controllers for the screen you're showing. Simplification may end up, as @J.Wang alludes to, solve your problem of calling methods on different objects. Your screen should be well handled with a TableViewController embedded in a Navigation Controller that has a button added to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
func refresh(){
    dump(cityArry)
    tableView.reloadData() 
}
```

to this:

```
func refresh(){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        dump(cityArry)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

If it happens that `refresh()` is getting called on anything other than the main thread the table view will likely not update properly. Might not be the issue but its a good first step.

Answer (score 0):

you need to reload data  in main thread in refresh function.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```